# Check if the value already exists in the database using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

**Description:** I have a site. I just want to keep track of a suspicious request and possible barn them only if needed. I just started to implement that feature. I have all the records of IP Addresses, but I'm not sure how to increment their visit count each time - they visit.

---

**Goal:** To increment `visit_count` attribute each time user visit a site

---

In my `visitors` table, I have an `ip` attribute
I want to check for an existing first before, I perform the saving, and other logics, but I'm just a little  stuck here.

How do I check if the value already exists in the database using Laravel ?

Any hints on this will be much appreciated !

---

I've tried

**Model : Visitor.php**

```
class Visitor extends Model {

    protected $table = 'visitors';


    //Validation Rules and Validator Function
    public static function validator($input, $id = ''){

        $rules = array(

            'ip'    =>'unique:visitors,ip,'.$id,

            );

        return Validator::make($input,$rules);
    }

}
```

---

**Controller : Visitor.php**

```
// Check for existing
$validator = Visitor::validator($ip);

if ($validator->fails()) {

    $ip = Visitor::where('ip', '=', $ip)->firstOrFail();
    $id =  $ip['attributes']['id']; //<------ Not sure if this is a proper way

    if($ip){

        $visitor              = Visitor::findOrFail($id);
        $visitor->visit_count = $visitor->visit_count + 1 ;
        $visitor->save();

    }

} else {

    $visitor              = new Visitor;

        $visitor->ip             = $ip;
        $visitor->visit_count    = $visitor->visit_count + 1 ;

    $visitor->save();

}
```

---

**Result**

I keep getting

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, string given

I believe, it from this line here `$validator = Visitor::validator($ip);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message kind of gives it away. The Validator expects the values and the rules to be two separate arrays, each with keys denoting the columns name that needs to be validated. You have that for the rules, but not for the values being checked. This will fix your error:

```
return Validator::make(['ip' => $input], $rules);
```

Comment: Trying it out now on my model. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Bogdan, can you take a quick look over my controller to see if I properly grabbing the `$id` for the right object ? I hope I am. If not, I can take some of your advice. :)

Comment: This line here `$id =  $ip['attributes']['id'];` <--- The app already work perfectly, but I'm just curious - if there is a better way of grabbing the `id` via Laravel methods or something like that.

Comment: The `findOrFail` method will return a `Visitor` model instance, so you should access the columns values as properties: `$id = $ip->id;`. But what you're doing there seems a little redundant because `Visitor::where('ip', '=', $ip)->firstOrFail()` already contains what `Visitor::findOrFail($id);` will return. So you only need this: http://pastebin.com/CNHWiVMe for that to work the same way.

Comment: Ohh I see. I should do that instead. Thanks for your advice.